# Linux image impossible to remove

Tags: boot, kernel, uninstall, removing

For some reason Ican't boot Ubuntu with the 5.13 kernel (it's stuck on the logo screen). When I launch Ubuntu with the previous version of the kernel (5.11) it works perfectly. I tried to remove the 5.13 version, but it keeps reinstalling it: `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` show this (I don't put the "rc" lines):

```
ii linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic
ii linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-27-generic
```

I try to uninstall the 5.13 kernel with this command line:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-27-generic
```

But during the uninstallation it installs me another version, and `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` gives this time:

```
ii linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic
ii linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic
```

And all of this back and forth. How can I completely remove the 5.13 kernel, as my Ubuntu doesn't launch with it?

Comment: Well, before mucking about with removal, did you troubleshoot and file a proper bug report on the problem with the 5.13 kernel? Kernels are not intentionally released with serious reversions like that

Comment: Yes, I spent almost one week trying to find a solution. Believe me, I'm not happy to have to remove the most version recent of the kernel, I don't find it clean at all, but for the moment all the answers concerning the 5.13 problem remain hopeless.

Comment: You might need to remove `linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04` first , as `linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic` is now its dependency.

Comment: if you go to /boot/ dir, do you see the: vmlinuz-5.13.0-27-generic and
initrd.img-5.13.0-27-generic?

Comment: have you tried to run ```update-grub```?

Comment: Let's check for a BIOS update that might fix your problem. Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @mikewhatever that is exactly what I do, but it always put a 5.13 again.

Comment: @Telegonicaxx yes

Comment: @heynnema `P1.70`

Comment: @djcaesar9114 You forgot to give me the make/model # of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: this is why I do a complete partition backup with clonezilla before updates.